# c++11: how to execute a function in the main thread after n seconds

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, timer

I need to stop a game after a certain amount of time. The stop method has to run in the main thread after, let's say, one minute.
In the meantime the player plays, so I cannot stop execution.
I'm trying to understand threads and async but I'm starting to think that none of them are useful in my situation (if I join, the user can't play; if I detach, the 'stop' method will be called in a separate thread). 
How could I deal with it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no generic c++11 way to do this, but if you specify the constraints - platform, what exaclty QT does (since you said you can't access the event loop or use signals/slots), how is your code invoked it could be possible to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just start your stop function with std::async, then inside of your stop function have a std::this_thread.sleep_for(60s) as a first call

e.g.

```
#include <future>
...
std::future<int> retCode = std::async(stop);
.. your game starts
```

inside of `int stop()`

```
int stop()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minute(1));
  ...do whatever to stop game...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "main thread" you are supposedly having an event loop, yes? Before the loop start, get the current time, and then in the loop get the current time again and check the difference between the first time and the current time in the loop.

Comment: there's no loop because the game dynamics is handled by QT library.. however I can't use qt signal/slots, so I cannot use QTimer...

Comment: @Surferonthefall QT most definitely has an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need/want to use Threads, You should have a look at the QtConcurrent Framework. 
The QRunnable QThreadPool is really easy to use.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html